# What is the state of the art in proof automation in HoTT/CuTT?

Tags: cubical-type-theory, automated, proof-search, homotopy-type-theory

One of the frequent criticisms of HoTT is that it requires a lot of lemmata keeping track of which types are sets/propositions etc. And a frequent counterpoint is "It can be automated."

However, internet searches don't seem to yield many results. Are there actually automation work going on?

Also, proof automation / proof search in cubical type theories seems to require new mechanisms. Is there any literature discussing this?

Comment: I don't think that HoTT, or even CuTT for that matter, is very different from CIC / MLTT in this aspect. Any automation technique that works for them will pretty much transport easily to the univalent case... For instance, proving hProp instances can be discharged by typeclasses or canonical structures.

Comment: @Pierre-MariePédrot The most brain-twisting part of coding in CuTT is to keep track of boundary conditions, which, MLTT/CIC solvers *cannot* do without significant changes. For instance, Agda currently gives up on non-trivial boundary conditions.

Comment: @Trebor can you say more about this (the type of automation you think is most needed for HoTT, or the problems in HoTT which are most “brain-twisting”) in your question?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Coq uses type classes to infer h-levels in some simple cases automatically ([see Sect. 3.2](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1610.04591.pdf)). Agda does not have an automatic way to manage or infer h-levels. I agree that one has to do quite a bit of bookkeeping to carry around proofs that something is of a certain h-level; and proving that newly introduced data types preserve a certain h-level requires quite lengthy encode-decode proofs (see for instance [this proof](https://github.com/agda/cubical/blob/master/Cubical/Data/List/Properties.agda#L109) that lists preserve the h-level of the carrier)

It's important to keep in mind that current formalizations of HoTT are still quite prototypical and based on proof assistants which had been devised before the idea of h-levels came to type theory. Future theorem provers will likely give more support to work with h-levels, possibly by introducing h-levels judgmentally like [Arend does](https://arend-lang.github.io/documentation/language-reference/definitions/level.html) (thereby giving an orthogonal stratification of types to universe levels).

Automating the bookkeeping should be an engineering task, deriving automated proofs about the h-level of a type or filling cubes in Cubical Agda is in general undecidable. I'm not aware of any work in this direction, but there are lots of interesting things to be done. Similarly to, e.g., termination checking, there are probably lots of things that can be done automatically even if the problem can't be solved in general.

Comment: Do you know if Arend’s built in support for h-levels is similar to what you had in mind?

Comment: I believe so, homotopy levels in Arend share many characteristics with truncation levels as studied in the HoTT book. However, I do not understand the theory behind Arend and can't say what is actually going on there.

Comment: Filling-cubes is actually undecidable even for squares since one can represent words problem of groups by using paths and squares. But it seems possible if your type has very simple fundamental group, it's kind of algebraic topology's business.

Comment: I'm not sure what post of mine you're referring to either.  I'm generally quite happy with the way that h-levels are inferred using typeclasses in Coq.  I don't use Agda as much, but in talking to people who do, I definitely notice that they're missing out on this automation and it's causing them pain.  Typeclasses can't infer everything, and there are probably some ways that the typeclass system could be improved, but by and large I think they infer most of what could reasonably be expected to be automatically inferrable.

Comment: Although Agda does have "instance arguments" which I think could be used in the same way in principle.

Comment: I'm not really thrilled with the idea of hardcoding the notion of h-level into the proof assistant.  It seems like mixing levels in the wrong way: for all its importance, the notion of h-level is not a primitive part of the type theory but something that we can define *in* that theory, so it should be dealt with using general user-configurable facilities that can also be applied to other analogous structures (like, for instance, other modalities).

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, and sorry for the mischaracterization. I've updated the answer.

Comment: I find that "truncating" a type by introducing higher paths is misleading from a computational point of view, as truncation does not erase, but introduce more structure. Having h-levels on a judgmental level might open up the possibility of properly erasing computational content, thereby adding a real benefit over h-levels defined internally (I haven't been able to work that out yet, so this is just a mere hope for now).

Comment: It might also depend on the use case -- for synthetic homotopy theory we might want internal h-levels, whereas some programming languages inspired by HoTT might use judgmental h-levels to manage how much structure is present in a type. Even if such type theories aren't faithfully modelling homotopy types, they might have some useful applications.

Comment: If you erase truncation, I think it is impossible to define maps from a truncation to a general type. You have to point out how to map the extra paths that introduced in truncation. It's not trivial, since different delegations lead to different maps and different results given by computation.

Comment: But if what you defined is map towards a truncation, then it is very reasonable to automate it. So no one needs to worry about paths higher than the truncated h-level. That's very annoying in practice, at least in my personal experience.

Comment: As I understand it, the typeclass system in Coq does not automate any encode-decode proofs – rather, it automates the finding of encode-decode lemmas which have already been manually proved – so I think it's a bit misleading to juxtapose those aspects.

Answer (score 2):

I'm surprised that the other answer poster Maximilian Doré did not mention their own work *Automating Kan composition* which is automation for cubical type theories: https://europroofnet.github.io/assets/wg6/stockholm-kickoff-slides/dore-europroofnet-stockholm-slides.pdf

It brute forces all possible hcomps by enumerating "compatible" faces.

Edit: paper is out: https://arxiv.org/abs/2402.12169

Comment: Thanks for mentioning this--I've been meaning to update my answer once a preprint is out (which is hopefully soon). The solver now works for different cubical type theories, and in the case of Dedekind cubes can do something a bit more clever than enumerating all faces.

Comment: @MaximilianDoré Could you please ping me when the preprint is out? Excited to see it